# How to alias a class method in rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to alias a class method on one of my Rails models.

```
  def self.sub_agent
   id = SubAgentStatus.where(name: "active").first.id
   where(type: "SubAgent",sub_agent_status_id: id).order(:first_name)    
  end
```

If this was an instance method, I would simply use `alias_method`, but that doesn't work for class methods. How can I do this without duplicating the method?

Answer (score 59):

You can use:

```
class Foo  
   def instance_method       
   end  

   alias_method :alias_for_instance_method, :instance_method

   def self.class_method
   end  

   class <<self  
     alias_method :alias_for_class_method, :class_method
   end  
 end
```

OR Try:

```
self.singleton_class.send(:alias_method, :new_name, :original_name)
```

Comment: I think someone forgot ~

Answer (score 2):

To add instance method as an alias for class method you can use `delegate :method_name, to: :class`

Example:

```
class World
  def self.hello
    'Hello World'
  end

  delegate :hello, to: :class
end

World.hello
# => 'Hello World'
World.new.hello
# => 'Hello World'
```

[Link on documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate)

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that:

```
class <<self
  alias_method :alias_for_class_method, :class_method
end
```

works perfectly even when it is inherited from a base class.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A quick reminder that would have gotten me to the right behaviour a bit faster is that this `alias_method`'ing should happen as the last thing of your `class` definition.

```
class Foo
  def self.bar(parameter)
    ....
  end

  ...

  singleton_class.send(:alias_method, :new_bar_name, :bar)
end
```

Good luck!
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo

  def self.sub_agent
    id = SubAgentStatus.where(name: "active").first.id
    where(type: "SubAgent",sub_agent_status_id: id).order(:first_name) 
  end

  self.singleton_class.send(:alias_method, :sub_agent_new, :sub_agent)

end
```